# Like button's link is not current page

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I just copied the like button link into my website.  However the link given when the button is clicked is not the current page, but a more general one in my website.

I placed the like button in all my sermon pages, which is:

```
jubilee.org.sg/sermons/?sermon_id=303
```

But the link given on the facebook page is only this:

```
jubilee.org.sg/sermons
```

How can I make it point to the right page?

Comment: Let me clarify: I placed the like button in all my sermon pages. e.g. http://www.jubilee.org.sg/sermons/?sermon_id=303.  But the link given on the facebook page is only this: http://www.jubilee.org.sg/sermons/

Comment: @Siow: when you need to clarify your question, edit it. Comments aren't meant to last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook ignores the query string parameter of your URL. You need to setup a new URL structure like /sermons/303.

Answer (score 0):

to change the url being picked by FB on diff pages you should use open graph tags..
specifically the  tag
see documentaion here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/